# strstr with udp client string and file string

Tags: c, string

I'm sending a string from a UDP client to a UDP server.
The server's job is to check if this string exists anywhere within a textfile archive.txt.

The problem I am getting is that strstr always returns null, even if my second string is in my first.

```
char msg[1000];
FILE *archive;
archive = fopen("archive.txt", "r");
char line[53];
char *testing;
```

.
   .
   .

```
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        n= recvfrom(sockfd,msg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
        sendto(sockfd,msg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
        msg[n]=0;
        while(fgets(line, 53, archive) !=NULL)
        {
            testing = strstr(line, msg);

            if(testing!=NULL)
               {printf("%s\n","Success");}
            else
            {    printf("%s\n", "fail");
                 printf("%s\n", line);  
                 printf("%s\n", msg);               
            }

        }
```

There are times when my program will print fail, the line and the msg where the msg is a substring of line.

Comment: are there non-printing characters in `msg` or `line`?  They may be there and just not obvious when displayed.  Try piping your output through `cat -v`.

Comment: There are no nonprinting characters when using cat -v

Comment: You do not seem to check `fopen`'s or `recvfrom`'s return values. Very bad things could happen.

Comment: i think you should write `msg[n] = '\0'` rather than plain 0.

Comment: No newlines either? fgets() returns the newline, do you transmit it?

Comment: Yeah newlines are fine. I think I figured out the answer, it was a couple of things wrong. Apparently msg length was always one extra character long with a blank space at the end. So the solution was to change my `msg[n]=0` into `msg[n-1]='\0'`. @AdityaKumar you can submit an answer now :)